# jqGrid doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am a newbie in Javascript and now trying to use jqGrid to load a table from database. However, it is ok to get xml string from database,but I cannot get it shown in html. Here is my code, I stored xml string to "tree.xml"

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My First Grid</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="gui/bootstrap3/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="gui/bootstrap3/css/ui.multiselect.css" />

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 75%;
}
</style> 
<script src="gui/bootstrap3/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="gui/bootstrap3/js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="gui/bootstrap3/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="gui/bootstrap3/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



jQuery().ready(function ({

 // alert("eff"); 

    $("#list").jqGrid({

    url: "tree.xml",
    datatype: "xml",
  //  mtype: "GET",
   colNames:['ID','Device Name', 'Location','Status'],
  colModel:[
  {name:'id',index:'PPID', width:55, sortable:true},
  {name:'devname',index:'DeviceName', width:90, editable:true},
  {name:'location',index:'Location', width:80, editable:true},
  {name:'status',index:'Status', width:150, editable:true}
],
    pager: jQuery("#pager"),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "id",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    caption: "My first grid"
}).navGrid( '#pager', {edit:false,add:false,del:false, search: false});

}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Start</h1>

    <table id="list"></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The xml string is like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rows>
  <page>1</page>
  <total>1</total>
  <records>9</records>
  <row id='1'>
    <cell>1</cell>
    <cell>D3200</cell>
    <cell>California</cell>
    <cell>DEPLOYED</cell>
  </row>
</rows>
```

**Update**
Finally I found this is a stupid error, there is an ')' missed at jQuery().ready() line. Thanks for attention!

Comment: Can you set up the jsfiddle so we can see what the server is returning.

Comment: Hi Marko, I have affixed the output xml string, The problem is even though I use local xml string ,there is still nothing displayed